# Capturing folder path from Windows Explorer

Tags: delphi, windows-explorer

I would like to add to a Delphi application a way for the user to call Windows Explorer (possibly using something like ShellExecute, perhaps).

However, and this is where I need some help, please, the application would need to capture ^H^H^H^H^H^H read the folder path that the user navigates to while within Windows Explorer.

Is it possible to obtain this information from Windows Explorer?

[edit: If not possible, or unrealistic, my fallback plan is to provide a separate "Browse for folder" button, to allow the user to select the folder first, then they can launch the Window explorer afterwards].

Thanks for any advice.
PhilW.

Comment: @PhilW Can you clarify this a little please, are you hoping to hook into Explorer.exe itself, or are you wanting to create an explorer like file dialog?

Comment: Capture the folder path, as in trap it and put it in a cage? I don't understand the question, please explain.

Comment: What's wrong with `TBrowseForFolder`?

Comment: @Reallyethical: Perhaps I'm asking the impossible, but I would like to give the user the power of the Windows Explorer, but also need to read and store the folder path which the user is working in.

Comment: @Cosmin: Thanks for responding; you have been a great help in my previous questions. Sorry for not using clear English, I have edited the question to provide more information.

Comment: @David: I am hoping to combine a 'Browse for folder' button and a 'Windows explorer' button in one. I'm probably being unrealistic. I have edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @PhilW: Do you know how to launch a "browse for folder" dialog?

Comment: @PhilW "Browse for folder" is difference from "Windows Explorer". Really, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know your exact needs, but most likely, this is not the way to go. For details, Microsoft developer Raymond Chen has written [a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/25/10145644.aspx) about this. What you should do, I think, is to embed an explorer browser control in a custom form in your own application.

Comment: Very interesting link, thank you. After reading the blog, I am a bit embarrassed that I was even contemplating doing what my question asked. Answer accepted with thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For letting a user browse to and select a folder, I use TOrtusShellBrowseFolder.

[Ortus Shell Components](http://www.delphicomponents.net/products)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the TOpenDialog?  From Delphi Help:

Description

TOpenDialog displays a modal Windows dialog box for selecting and opening files. The dialog does not appear at runtime until it is activated by a call to the Execute method. When the user clicks Open, the dialog closes and the selected file or files are stored in the Files property.

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
   filename := OpenDialog1.FileName;
```

Comment: Hello Leslie, it may come to this, but I was hoping to have my cake and eat it by giving the user the full power of the Explorer but also to track and store the folder path they were using. I think you make a good point that this is a standard function which users are familiar and understand how to use, even though it may take them a bit longer to complete.